# Mongo Client RedHat EL5 UT8 Support

Tags: redhat, mongodb, utf-8

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.4
Fri Mar 16 11:55:46 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support. consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test
```

Mongo Server seems to handle the utf8 characters fine, as well as my php-mongo-client driver.

But when I try to query a record that has a utf8 character from the mongo command line client I get:

```
> db.Users.find({age:33});
error:non ascii character detected
Fri Mar 16 11:55:43 mongo got signal 11 (Segmentation fault), stack trace: 

Fri Mar 16 11:55:43 0x440b50 0x3664c302d0 0x3f47e7b6e0 0x3f47e83bbd 0x3f47e254f3 0x3f47e25660 0x3f47e256ee 0x3f47e25792 0x3f47e2876e 0x4b031d 0x443b72 0x445476 0x3664c1d994 0x43fd39
 mongo(_Z12quitAbruptlyi+0x3b0) [0x440b50]
 /lib64/libc.so.6 [0x3664c302d0]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1 [0x3f47e7b6e0]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1(js_CompileTokenStream+0x3d) [0x3f47e83bbd]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1 [0x3f47e254f3]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1(JS_CompileUCScriptForPrincipals+0x60) [0x3f47e25660]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1(JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals+0x3e) [0x3f47e256ee]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1(JS_EvaluateUCScript+0x22) [0x3f47e25792]
 /usr/lib64/libjs.so.1(JS_EvaluateScript+0x6e) [0x3f47e2876e]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo7SMScope4execERKSsS2_bbbi+0xed) [0x4b031d]
 mongo(_Z5_mainiPPc+0x14a2) [0x443b72]
 mongo(main+0x26) [0x445476]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4) [0x3664c1d994]
 mongo(__gxx_personality_v0+0x269) [0x43fd39]
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mongo version 1.6.4 was installed by the package management system, which includes the mongo init scripts.

The solution I came up with was to download the newest Mongo(2.0.3) binaries from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads. Then I replaced all the binaries from the rpm `/usr/bin` with the ones I downloaded.

Everything now works perfectly!

Comment: Michael - if you want a package management solution with the latest version, 10gen (the creators of MongoDB) have their own repos: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages or http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CentOS+and+Fedora+Packages

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. MongoDB **shell version: 1.8.2** on **Ubuntu** (EC2)

> > db.tweets.find();
>
> error:non ascii character detected

Checked which version of MongoDB I was running by issuing the command:

> $ mongod --version
>
> db version **v1.8.2**, pdfile version 4.5 - 
>   Wed Oct 24 15:43:13 git version: nogitversion

*Confirm* if mongo is currently running:

> $ ps -deaf | grep **mongod**
>
> **mongodb  15408**     1  0 Jun06 ?  13:50:00 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

To [Shutdown MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Starting+and+Stopping+Mongo)

> $ ./mongo
>
> > use admin
>
> > db.shutdownServer()
>
> server should be down...

Then upgraded following these instructions: [How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Add the 10 Gen (creators of MongoDB) public key to apt-get so you trust their package:

> $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
>
> $ echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list

Update your packages:

> $ sudo apt-get update

install 10gen's MongoDB Debian/Ubuntu package:

> $ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
>
> The following packages will be **REMOVED**:
>     **mongodb**
>
> The following **NEW** packages will be installed:
>     **mongodb-10gen**

*If you get an error*, try:

> $ apt-get autoremove

once you have the new version of MongoDB the "non ascii" character issue should be gone.

(p.s. I know this question relates to **RHEL** but people running *other versions* of Linux will come up against this issue so I thought a Ubuntu/Debian answer was relevant. Feel free to  remove

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+Spider+Monkey#BuildingSpiderMonkey-Build

"SpiderMonkey does not use UTF-8 by default, so we enable before building."

So, you'll need to rebuild SpiderMonkey.

Comment: I had previously looked into this. However, being that I was on a production server I wanted minimal impact.